# Определение нажатого элемента в контекстном меню

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Здравствуйте! В Silverlitght windows phone toolkit есть элемент управления контекстное меню. Так вот, в самом тулките приводиться пример использования меню в одиночных обьектах, я же использую меню в списке и, поэтому, не могу разобраться как после нажатия на один из пунктов контекстного меню определить для какого элемента списка вызвано это меню. Все это дело усложняется тем, что в примере тулкита нет примера создания меню в коде, только в разметке xaml. Помогите бывалые, пожалуйста!
Вот кусок кода контекстного меню в xaml:

```
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
   <toolkit:ContextMenu>
      <toolkit:MenuItem Header="добавить в..." Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
      <toolkit:MenuItem Header="переименовать"/>
      <toolkit:MenuItem Header="удалить"/>
      <toolkit:MenuItem Header="доп. информация" Click="ShowFileInfo"/>
   </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С каждым пунктом меню нужно ассоциировать команду. Примерно так (где `YourList` -- это имя списка, к которому привязан список):

```
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
   <toolkit:ContextMenu>
      <toolkit:MenuItem Header="добавить в..."
          Command={ElementName=YourList, Path=DataContext.AddItemCommand}/>
      <toolkit:MenuItem Header="доп. информация"
          Command={ElementName=YourList, Path=DataContext.ShowItemInfoCommand}/>
   </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Вью модель (с использованием `RelayCommand` из [MvvmLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net)):

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

public class SomeViewModel
{
    // для привязки к списку
    public ObservableCollection<SomeItem> Items { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand<SomeItem> AddItemCommand { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand<SomeItem> ShowItemInfoCommand { get; set; }

    public MessagesViewModel()
    {
        AddItemCommand = new RelayCommand<SomeItem>(OnAddItem);
        ShowItemInfoCommand = new RelayCommand<SomeItem>(OnShowItemInfo);
    }

    private void OnAddItem(SomeItem item)
    {
        ...
    }

    private void OnShowItemInfo(SomeItem item)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Я добрался до элемента списка так:

'private async void ContextMenuItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ViewItem = ((ViewItem)((FrameworkElement)((ContextMenu)((MenuItem)sender).Parent).Owner).DataContext);}'

вроде работает, но не знаю правильно это или нет))
Спасибо за подсказку, Ваш метод использую когда доберусь до реализации MVVM-модели

Comment: @RomanNomokonov буду краток -- используйте MVVM :).